# Is error recovery possible in Java?

Tags: java, error-handling

Consider the following code which generates StackOverflowError.

```
public class SimpleProgram {
  static SimpleProgram s = new SimpleProgram();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      s.f(0);
  }

  void f(int i) {
      System.out.println("f :" + (++i));
      g(i);
  }

  void g(int i) {
      System.out.println("g :" + (++i));
      f(i);
  }
}
```

It simply prints the number from 1 to n ( '5417' by f() when I executed ). After that it throws StackOverflowError and terminates. Now consider the second program.

```
public class SimpleProgram{
  static SimplePrograms = new SimpleProgram();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      s.f(0);
  }

  void f(int i) {
      try {
          System.out.println("f :" + (++i));
          g(i);
      } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
          System.out.println("f :" + (++i));
          g(i);
      }
  }

  void g(int i) {
      try {
          System.out.println("g :" + (++i));
          f(i);
      } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
          System.out.println("g :" + (++i));
          f(i);
      }
  }
}
```

Now it shows some strange behavior. The program doesn't terminate as expected, but the values displayed are repeated ( say f :4107 g :4108 to f :4120 and again back to f :4107).

My question is, why is this happening? I thought an error like StackOverflowError means the current thread's stack is full and hence there is no recovery. The program has to stop it's execution forcefully i.e doesn't call next function, but didn't happen. 
Can JVM thread stack increase its size on demand?

Comment: It is happening because that is what you have instructed your program to do. You caught the exception, and then retry the recursive call, which might or might not throw yet another exception (depending on stack allocation requirements), so your recursion will bob up and down the stack one or two frames and never end as you don't end it.

Comment: I wonder if JLS or JVMS tells any details about JVM state when StackOverflowError is caught? E.g., how many stack frames discarded, if any? This question implies that some stack space must be freed to permit calls from `catch` block.

Comment: @VictorSorokin None: it is thrown when the method invocation cannot allocate enough space on the stack for the invoked method, returning control to the current method (the one that invoked the method that caused the stack overflow). If the exception is not caught, the stack is unwound until it is caught just like happens for any other exception.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but here several calls from `catch` block work, although only one frame is discarded when error thrown (since handler is in immediate caller).

Comment: @VictorSorokin As far as I can tell that observed behavior depends if the method throwing the stackoverflow exception is called from the try or the catch (and if that method has been called from the try or the catch, and so on). So my comment "will bob up and down the stack one or two frames" is not correct.

Comment: dasblinkenlights' answer explains behavior nicely -- stack freed due to error being thrown while already inside `catch` block, so exception can propagate further than one call frame.

Answer (score 2):

Your exception handlers makes more method calls (to `System.out.println()` and either `f()` or `g()`). These calls may throw a new `StackOverflowError`, which may be caught a few levels down the call stack, so you'll see the numbers going down and back up infinitely (since as the exception goes down the methods in the call stack, some space is freed in the call stack, so there's room for additional calls to be made).

Here's part of the output I got (to make it clearer, I added "catch" to the `println` statements inside the catch blocks) :

The first `StackOverflowError` happens when `System.out.println(String)` attempts to call `println()`, which is why no new line is displayed in `g :9662catch g :9663`. For some reason, after the first `StackOverflowError`, there is room to about 50 additional calls until we get another `StackOverflowError`, after which the errors come more periodically.

```
... no eception till this point...
g :9660
f :9661
g :9662catch g :9663 
f :9664
g :9665
f :9666
g :9667
f :9668
g :9669
f :9670
g :9671
f :9672
g :9673
f :9674
g :9675
f :9676
g :9677
f :9678
g :9679
f :9680
g :9681
f :9682
g :9683
f :9684
g :9685
f :9686
g :9687
f :9688
g :9689
f :9690
g :9691
f :9692
g :9693
f :9694
g :9695
f :9696
g :9697
f :9698
g :9699
f :9700
g :9701
f :9702
g :9703catch g :9704catch f :9703
g :9704catch g :9705catch g :9702
f :9703
g :9704catch g :9705catch f :9704
g :9705catch g :9706catch f :9701
g :9702
f :9703
g :9704catch g :9705catch f :9704
g :9705catch g :9706catch g :9703
f :9704
g :9705catch g :9706catch f :9705
g :9706catch g :9707catch g :9700
f :9701
g :9702
f :9703
g :9704catch g :9705catch f :9704
g :9705catch g :9706catch g :9703
f :9704
g :9705catch g :9706catch f :9705
g :9706catch g :9707catch f :9702
g :9703
f :9704
g :9705catch g :9706catch f :9705
g :9706catch g :9707catch g :9704
f :9705
....
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is quite convincing. When I encountered this for the first time, I thought that thread stack can grow its size. But that contradicts the theory and the numbers printed does not progress. So I got confused.

Answer (score 2):

What you see has to do with the way your program is constructed more than with the way Java handles errors. Your program creates two points of retry at each of `n` invocation levels, so the total number of paths through the program grows exponentially.

Let's consider what would happen if only three call levels were sufficient to overflow the stack:

```
main -> f(0)
f(0) -> g(0)
g(0) -> f(1)
f(1) -> g(1)
g(1) -> f(2)
f(2) -> g(2)
g(2) -> f(3) <<== Stack overflow
```

What happens next? The stack begins unwinding. Each method has installed a handler for `StackOverflowError`, so they would be handling the error and calling the same function again:

```
g(2) handler -> f(3) <<== Stack overflow #2
f(2) handler -> g(2)
g(2) -> f(3)         <<== Stack overflow #3
g(2) handler -> f(3) <<== Stack overflow #4
g(1) handler -> f(2)
f(2) -> g(2)
g(2) -> f(3)         <<== Stack overflow #5
f(1) handler -> g(1)
g(1) -> f(2)
f(2) -> g(2)
g(2) -> f(3)         <<== Stack overflow #6
g(0) handler -> f(1)
f(1) -> g(1)
g(1) -> f(2)
f(2) -> g(2)
g(2) -> f(3)         <<== Stack overflow #7
f(0) handler -> g(0)
g(0) -> f(1)
f(1) -> g(1)
g(1) -> f(2)
f(2) -> g(2)
g(2) -> f(3)         <<== Stack overflow #8
```

As you can see, this chain unwinds eventually, but it goes up and down many times for only three levels. With thousands of levels, the number would be much higher: the count of errors your get goes up two times for each `f` or `g` level on the way to overflow, so it is 2<sup>n</sup> for `n` frames. With `n` in the thousands, you can consider your program infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. This actually gives an idea of how the handling works. In this case, like you said the call to the function from try block causing an error makes the same call from catch block. But I don't understand why the unwinding happens since error is not thrown but handled. Say, f(0) calls g(0), then g(1) calls f(1) and if error occurs over here then catch g(2) calls f(2) and it's error again. So it unwind to previous f(0). But why will catch of f(0) execute, since no error is in this call?

Comment: @Balu Here unwinding happens because each error handling causes "winding back" to the error, which installs new error handlers again, and requires new unwinding before hitting the next level down. Invocation trees in the `try` and the `catch` are the same, so if the `try` subtree needs X catches, `catch` subtree would have `X` catches as well, for 2X+1 catches altogether.

Comment: @Balu The catch in `f(0)` will be executed once; the catch in `g(0)` will be executed twice - for the `try` of `f(0)` and for the catch of `f(0)`. The catch of `f(1)` will be executed four times - for the `try` in `f(0)` and `try` in `g(0)`, the `try` in `f(0)` and `catch` in `g(0)`, the `catch` in `f(0)` and `try` in `g(0)`, and the `catch` in `f(0)` and `catch` in `g(0)`. The catch in `g(1)` is executed eight times; the catch in `f(2)` - 16 times, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I think, it makes perfect sense. But I needed a paper and a pen for diagrammatic representation, to understand.